# Creating new windows that run programs in screen

Tags: gnu-screen

My `.screenrc` has some initialization code that opens some windows.  It's neat.

What I want to do, while running screen is simply , with one command open a new screen window that is running a program.

It SHOULD be:

```
screen -t 'CADMIN' sudo cherokee-admin -b
```

This actually works, except that it also runs my .screenrc and opens up all of my
windows in a nested screen.  FAIL.

I know I could use

```
^c ( to create a new window )   
^cA ( to title it )   
sudo cherokee-admin -b
```

and get the same effect, but I'd like to bring a little elegance to my life, which
is why I use screen and not some multi terminal thing.

Ideas?

Comment: Update:  I notice that if i skip the -t switch , it only opens the one window, as expected.   Still, I'd kind of like to open a named window... seems like if screen sudo cherokee-admin -b opens a single unamed windown running my cherokee admin, then I should be able to add a title to it without going to the screen, no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I've got a somewhat palatable answer:

from [the bugs page](https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?26633)  there is a discussion about problems using the screen -t invocation.

I've tried this and I find that `screen -c /dev/null -t CADMIN sudo cherokee-admin -b` actually works the way I originally thought it would.  It's kind of nifty actually, -c calls nothing for the value of .screenrc, which does not open my glorious screen rig.  I can live with this.

Answer (score 0):

You could setup another .screenrc file that doesn't have all of the other windows in it then in your .bash_profile you could add something like:

```
alias scn="screen -c '.screenrc2' -t 'CADMIN' sudo cherokee-admin -b"
```

then all you would have to do is run $scn from the cli to open screen with the desired effect.

hope this helps

edit: Make sure you name the second .screenrc file something different (i.e. '.screenrc2')